# Boost.Iterator Facade with an incomplete Value argument

Tags: c++, templates, boost, iterator

I'm trying to use `boost::iterator_facade` with an incomplete `Value`
template argument. This fails, because `iterator_facade` is trying to
check if the type `is_pod`.

Is this the expected behavior? Can I work around this limitation in
some way? I could write a class template that simply proxies `foo` and
provides implicit conversion to it, but I'd rather have a simpler
solution.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

class iter
  : public boost::iterator_facade< iter,
                                   iter,
                                   boost::forward_traversal_tag
                                   >
{
private:
  friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

  void increment() {  }

  bool equal(iter const& other) const { return true; }

  iter& dereference() const { return const_cast<iter&>(static_cast<const iter&>(*this)); }
};


int main()
{
  iter f;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just stumbled on exactly the same problem. Seems boost developers tried to be too smart, and overlooked the above case, which is common even for many iterators in the standard library.

Comment: @ybungalobill I'll add a bounty, but I doubt this will help.

Comment: [Note that it's a known issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1315). Also what I said is wrong, there are standard iterators which return themselves from operator* but their value_type is defined to be `void`.

Comment: @ybungalobill I've looked at the issue tracker but couldn't find this particular issue. Given the age it is rather unlikely to ever be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is_pod a problem can't you just specialize it with iter type?

On ideone - http://ideone.com/1DR8v - it seems to be working that way, even if type in not defined at all and is_pod is specialized with that incomplete type.

Comment: For strange reasons I have to specialize `is_POD` instead of `is_pod`, but this set me off in the right direction. http://codepad.org/GwZu7PJa